# Matching pattern with fraction

Tags: regex

I am using regular expression to validate a pattern followed by a fraction. I found these and they match what I need. Overall I want to match `1 to 2` numbers followed by the fraction. How are these expressions different?

```
/^[0-9]+(?:[\xbc\xbd\xbe])$/ugm

/^\d+(?:[\xbc\xbd\xbe])$/ugm

/^\w+(?:\w+)$/ugm
```

I need to match the following:

```
12½
1¼
11¾
```

but not match..

```
111½
11111¼ 
0¾
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well to begin with, `[0-9]` matches any character of: (`0` to `9`) and is not the same as `\d`

`\d` matches digits (`0-9`) and other digit characters such as [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode).

`\w` matches any word character (*letter*, *number*, or *underscore*)

Although these given expressions may match the same pattern, you will eventually fail using your **3rd** solution. 
It will match a pattern like `foobar` where as you can see there are no (`0-9`) characters or Unicode fractions in this pattern.

And with running a quick benchmark, your **2nd** solution is about `16%` slower than your first, plus it matches Unicode and other digit characters.

I would stick with your first expression, and change it to match between `1-2` number characters.

```
/^[1-9][0-9]?(?:[\xbc\xbd\xbe])$/ugm
```

or even

```
/^[1-9][0-9]?(?:[\xbc-\xbe])$/ugm
```

Comment: Glad that I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
^[1-9][0-9]?[\xbc\xbd\xbe]$
```

`[0-9]` and `\d` are equivalent. `\w` matches a "word" character. The expression `[1-9]` matches a digit which is not zero (since you specifically asked how to exclude that).

This unattractively hard-codes for some legacy 8-bit character set; for future compatibility, you should consider switching to Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
 /^[1-9][0-9]?(?:[\xbc\xbd\xbe])$/ugm
```

Comment: It should be `[1-9][0-9]`. You should remove the `+`.

Comment: It should be `[1-9][0-9]?`.  It needs to match one- and two-digit numbers.

Comment: The parentheses `(?:...)` do not seem to serve any purpose.